# Implementing jacknife method

Tags: probability-or-statistics, undocumented, code-request

I need to use a jacknife method in order to find the standard deviation of my data. Howvere, I realise there's no built-in fuction (or maybe I couldn't find it), not even a general bootstrap method.

Is there any built-in function or where I can find some reference in order to make it efficent?

Thanks

Comment: `StandardDeviation[data]` ?

Comment: I know that function, but I must use (as a requirement) a bootstrap method.

Comment: replace each observation with the mean of the sample that excludes that observation: `data2 = Mean /@ Subsets[data, {Length[data] - 1}]` then use `StandardDeviation` on the new dataset:
`StandardDeviation[data2]`?

Comment: The jackknife estimate of the standard error of the sample mean is just the usual estimate of standard deviation divided by the square root of the sample size: `StandardDeviation[data]/Sqrt[Length[data]]`.  So you'll need to be more specific than the "standard deviation of my data".  What particular statistic are you interested in using the jackknife?  Mean?  Variance? the square of the mean?